# Rendering and printing stuff with PHP: PDF, HTML or ...?

Tags: php, html, pdf, printing, render

I'm coding a system to manage Teams in a event, and i need to print badges for each person in the event.

I need to print other stuffs also (with a lot of custom information), and i was wondering how would i do, to correcly put each badge, or Schedule, in one page (Without having to split it when printing...).

What is better to use, and to deal with?

HTML, PDF or is there another solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: if you are in control of the printer i would just print from html, pdf would seem to be a needles complication.

Comment: @Ivan Seidel how did you solve the badge printing? I am running into a similar issue/question. In my case the team thinks about using an evolis badge printer. I never seen this printer "live", but as i understand it, it is a printer dedicated to printing badges. Any info or suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say use HTML and create a CSS stylesheet that is specifically for print.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be best generating a PDF in php, and then printing it from your browser. Look into mPDF. You can design the badge with css & html, and then it can convert the HTML into a PDF for you.

If you are running php in windows, you can even look into the printer extension to print directly from PHP.